# Could not autowire. No beans of 'StateMachineFactory<States, Events>' type found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

```java
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class StateMachineConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter
    <States, Events> {
    // configuring...
}

public enum Events {
    CONFIRM_RESET,
    CANCEL_RESET
    // other events
}

public enum States {
    INITIAL,
    STARTING_ORDER
    // other states
}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class OrderService {
    @Autowired
    private StateMachineFactory<States, Events> stateMachineFactory;

    // Could not autowire. No beans of 'StateMachineFactory<States, Events>' type found.
}
```

`@EnableStateMachineFactory` annotation does not work. Could not autowire. No beans of `StateMachineFactory<States, Events>'` type found.

In the same time after using `@EnableStateMachine` I can autowire 1 statemachine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.statemachine</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-statemachine-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

oh, this is a version of boot starter problem, i change my version from 2.2.1 to 2.5.4 and the problem get away